# Recommendations for a .NET UDP component

Tags: .net, udp

I'm looking for recommedations for a .NET UDP component/library that supports async calls.  It can be for .NET 2.0 or later, with our preference being that it supports 4.0.  It doesn't have to be free, but of course, free is good too.  :-)

I know that we could write our own, but time is limited and the budget allows for us to purchase one.  But the question is which one?

Comment: Erm, just use the one in the framework (BCL)? Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx).

My overall suggestion is that you always start by looking in the .NET Framework before looking for outside libraries.

Comment: It appears that the UdpClient works in "blocking synchronous mode".  That doesn't really meet my needs.  Or did I miss something?

Comment: well... apparently I did miss something... simple and obvious at that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163648.aspx search ProtocolType.Udp

I havent used it before but this may be what your looking for [Socket Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx), and [Socket Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket_members.aspx).

Comment: The MSDN article was very informative.  Thanks for educating me.